# Каким должен быть класс для умного устроства?

Tags: ооп, чистый-код, iot

Смотрите. Вопрос простой по "чистому коду". Есть умное устройство в сети. Оно имеет свою функциональность и свою память - свойства, хранящиеся на этом устройтве. Вот в чем вопорос. Я могу создать класс `Device`, который будет хранить кеш устройства и функциональность, и могу создать класс `DeviceController`, который будет управлять сразу несколькими устройствами делегируя им команды. Как лучше? Хранить лишь свойтва в `Device`, а контроллер сам будет отправлять команды в `Device` переданный в его метод, или все же первый вариант с полноценным функциональным класом `Device`? А, да. Забыл сказать. Устройство поддерживает два типа соединения. Клиент-сервер и сервер-клиент. Т. е. переключаются режимы соединения. И опять же  я могу передать режим в метод `Device`, или сразу `DeviceController` будет командовать в определенном режиме. Проблема в том что класс `Device` становится слишком громоздким, ну мне так кажется. Вопрос чисто этический) Т. е. разница. Либо будет `контроллер.устройство[1].включись()`, либо `контроллер.включить(устройство[1])`. Групповые команды в любом случае будут управляться контроллером.